# Fetch local branch to another branch without merging

Tags: git

I plan to have two branches.

```
dev - contains code with addional logging output
production - contains only code, without logging output
```

I just created a new commit in **dev**:

```
$x = getFoo();
$this->logger->info("Value of x: '$x'");
...
```

Now I changed to the **production** branch and try to fetch the local branch dev, without merging it, so that I can remove the logging debug output and create a commit with the same commit message as in dev branch.

**Attempt:**

So I tried to fetch the local **dev** branch, but I get:

```
$ git fetch dev
fatal: 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### if `dev` branch is one commit ahead

If the branch is only one commit ahead, then I prefer the `cherry-pick` [solution from @torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782717/4684797).
This has the advantage that it will only include the changes since the last commit without all logging code.

### if `dev` branch is multiple commits ahead:

```
git diff production dev > patch
git checkout production
git apply patch
```

Answer (score 3):

`git fetch` is the wrong command for this:

- You made a commit, locally, on one of your branch names.
- Then you switched to some other branch name.  This other name selects a different commit: not the commit you just made, where you added some code, including some debug code.  The commit you have selected now includes *neither* the new code *nor* the new debug code.
- You now want to take the stuff that you already committed—i.e., that you already have—and use that to do some additional work on the files you have extracted from this *other* branch and its *different* commit, without making a new commit.

The `git fetch` command is about getting commits from *some other* repository.  You don't need to do that!  You *already have the commit you want*, in *your own* repository, right now.

The command that's closest to the right one for this is `git cherry-pick`.  This command isn't really a *solution*, though: it's just a tool, like `git diff` or `git apply`.  Its default is to do a sort of diff-and-apply-and-commit, all in one.  You want a sort of diff-and-apply without the commit.  Fortunately, that's easy to get: just add `-n` to the cherry-pick command:

```
git checkout production
git cherry-pick -n dev
```

Unfortunately, this has the side effect of *also* doing the equivalent of:

```
git add <files>
```

where the files are the ones modified by the diff-and-apply.  That's not a big problem, really, but it means that you'll want to clean up the debug prints and re-run the `git add`s.

Comment: I tried it, it works good if the `dev` branch is ahead by only one commit, but if it is ahead by multiple commits, then it just loads the latest commit from the dev branch. Is there a solution for this too?

Comment: In this case, you have the option of cherry-picking multiple commits (if that's what you'd like as your result, i.e., multiple commits) or of using `git merge --squash` or equivalent (if that's what you would like), or of using `git merge --no-commit` (if that's what you'd like), or using any of Git's other various tools. There are many tools. Decide what *result* you want first, then pick the tools that will get you there.

Comment: I tried `git merge dev --no-commit` but there are many conflicts. I think the best solution is my patch workaround in this case.